In Weka, how can I change the the minimum support as required?
I was required to vary the minimum support for Apriori and the confidence 10 times as the following and report the number of rules table 1 and plot 1: (support, confidence):
(0.005, 0.8), (0.01, 0.8), (0.05, 0.8), (0.1, 0.8), (0.15, 0.8).
When I try to set up different minimum support, the results that I got were same. The minimum support value didn't change. How can I run the result with required parameters?

